# creating enum and float data type in doctrine and symfony 2

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I am using symfony 2 with doctrine. Doctrine does not seem to have enum data type.

My first question is how to set up enum data type so that when creating the actual tables from the entity, column having this enum data type is also reflected in the table structure.

Doctrine supports float data type but how to setup datatype as float(10,2). I tried following in my yaml meta data:

```
weight:
  type: float
  scale: 2
```

This did not work for me. I read the documentation and says it requires setLocale for scale to work. How do I fix this in symfony 2?